# Detect network hardware causes iDRAC to disconnect

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

I have a Dell Poweredge R610 server which is connected to a 10.0.0.0/29 network. This server has iDRAC enterprise and the NIC selection set to shared with static IP address 10.0.0.6.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on this server and during the "Detect network hardware" step iDRAC's IP (10.0.0.6) becomes inaccessible and I need to use KVM-IP to proceed further. Until the server is rebooted the IP stays inaccessible. Why is it so?

iDRAC firmware revision is 1.92.05

### UPDATE:

I updated the iDRAC firmware to 1.99 but the problem still persists.

Comment: I assume you have done all available firmware and BIOS updates?

Comment: @FalconMomot No, I haven't updated anything.